# Кнопки как в App Store

Tags: qt

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в Qt такой виджет?
[image: Такой]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть [такая](https://github.com/benadler/FancyTabBar) панелька из QtCreator, правда не знаю на сколько она похожа на App Store по функциям.